# Is it possible to set an IAM policy and as a condition, remove it when the account is gone

Tags: google-iam, google-deployment-manager

Looking for the setIamPolicy, saw that is possible to set a condition for the policy. For example:

```
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:my-project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin
  condition:
    title: expirable access
    description: Does not grant access after Sep 2020
    expression: request.time < timestamp('2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z')
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy

I would like to create a custom condition, which the Policy will be removed after the account is removed. Is it possible? Didn't found any example in the link below:

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) is currently in private beta the chances of a community member to be whitelisted for this feature are incredibly low.

I advise you to [ask directly to Google](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) if the feature to set IAM policy as a condition is supported